# How To add array of DatagridView control on panel vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have to add the `Datagridview` control at run time 1 below another on panel. how could i achieve this so that i'll be able to add controls location 1 below another, and how could i handle the click event, paint event and ect. for all datagridview.

Comment: If you have a question with `vb.net` don't use `c#` tag.

Comment: Hi syed mohsin, i got this link on net http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?662230-RESOLVED-How-to-create-a-DataGridView-control-array-at-runtime. so i have to add datagridview 1 after another on panel.

Comment: is your question how to handle events from two different datagridviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
Dim lastCtrl As Control
Panel1.Add(AllDataGrids(0))

For i As Integer = 1 to AllDataGrids.Count - 1
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = AllDataGrids(i)

    lastCtrl = Panel1.Controls(Panel1.Controls.Count - 1)
    Panel1.Add(dgv)

    dgv.Top = lastCtrl.Top + LastCtrl.Height + 5
Next
```

The idea is to add each control after the last one, so in the loop you get the last one in the way you want, and then add the new control on the bottom. In order to have the events you have to add them manually for each `DataGridView` inside the loop with:

```
AddHandler dgv.CellClick, AddressOf CellClickMethod
```

Comment: Hi SysDragon, i did some change in your code and got it working..! Thanks.

Comment: Hi SysDragon, I added the 10 datagridview 1 after another. but it taking time for rendering so it look blurring, while scrolling among them.I've added the DoubleBuffered to each datagridview but no effect is there any solution for it..?

Comment: You can ask another question about rendering options.

Comment: Okay.I asked the new question,Thanks.